# Why can't I combine these two plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the data

```
    list = {{100,5.98211},{150,7.30111},{200,8.4106},{250,9.37018},{300,10.3357},{350,10.8954},{400,12.1995},{450,12.5962},{500,12.9723},{550,14.0764},{600,14.5038},{650,15.2934},{700,15.5911},{750,16.1751},{800,16.9177},{850,17.3917},{900,17.9421},{950,18.5718},{1000,18.8729}}
```

now I fit the logarithm of the data with a function

```
Fit[Log@list2, {1, Log@x}, x]
(*Out = -2.69443 + 2.89979 Log[x]*)
```

Now finally I want to combine the graphics

```
s = Plot[%, {x, 1, 1000}];
s2 = ListLogPlot[list2];
Show[s,s2]
```

But this produces only one graph

[image]

I suspect this is because the `ListLogPlot`, but how do I fix this?

Comment: Use `LogPlot` instead of `Plot` (or `ListPlot` instead of `ListLogPlot`).

Comment: But I would need to have a different fit no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not fitting your data correctly, because you take a logarithm for $x$ values twice. Instead, you should write

```
Fit[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ list, {1, Log@x}, x]
```

Even better, use [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[list, a x^b, {a, b}, x]
Show[Plot[fit[x], {x, 1, 1000}], ListPlot[list]]
```

[image]